# GWT SplitLayoutPanel block movement

Tags: java, gwt

I have create a SplitLayoutPanel i need to block the movement when i press one button.how can do?

```
SplitLayoutPanel splitPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel();
```

Comment: You want to disable the draggable layout after pressing a button?

Comment: yes i need to block drag on request

Comment: Please post an update whether you were able to solve the problem. It is a nice practice to close the question if it gets solved either by choosing an answer or by posting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have direct api's to handle this. You should be able to hack up SplitLayoutPanel to do this.

Step 1 - Copy SplitLayoutPanel into your code base but ensure it has the same package as in gwt.

Step 2 - Add a boolean flag and relevant apis to track disabling of Drag.

```
boolean dragEnabled;
setDragEnabled(boolean dragEnabled)
{
  this.dragEnabled=dragEnabled;
}
```

Step 3 - SplitLayoutPanel  has a "Splitter" inner class. In onBrowserEvent code do something like this

```
onBrowserEvent(){
 if(dragEnabled){
   Do the normal thing. Copy the existing code.
 }else{
   Do nothing!!!
 }
}
```